# I am trying to make ListView ReadOnly and can't setup Enable property to false because I need allow user use scroll bar

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-3.0

I am trying to make ListView ReadOnly and can't setup Enable property to false because I need allow user use scroll bar in winforms. I have checkboxes in listview as listview_items.
  I want to keep one item default select and don't allow user to select another item in listview,but allow user to scroll the listview
 I have tried many things like handling mouse click event and keypress event,but i didn't get the solution..
   Plz help me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @matzone:  How to make listview item of type Checkbox is readonly/disabled?? I have tried a lot

Comment: @matzone: 
  Here is my listItem-
      ListViewItem lst = new ListViewItem(item.GetFullText);
                    lst.Tag = item.ItemDetailsId;
                    lst.Name = item.GetFullText;

Comment: is there anybody who can help me out here?I'm stuck over here from past 4-5 days plz ...

Comment: Try my answer if you don't figured it out yet ...

Answer (score 1):

You can apply this ..

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemChecked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemChecked
    Dim x As Integer = e.Item.Index

    If e.Item.Checked Then
        For n As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
            If Not n = x Then ListView1.Items.Item(n).Checked = False
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Modify the code as your purposes ..

Comment: :Thanks for solution i figured out another solution for it.

Comment: @user2067120 You should add your solution as an answer to this question.